# mongo main routing server with failover or redundancie

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo cluster of 1 Main routing mongoserver, with 3 shards server en 3 config servers. Each shard have a primary mongo database, a secundairy mongo database and an arbiter mongo database.

The shards are redundant (Primary mongoserver and Replication mongoserver).
The Config servers are redundant. (3 config server)

Only the main routing mongoserver is not redundant.
So this is a single point of failure.

Is there a way within mongo to expend this routing mongoserver, so that there is a failover/redundant functionality?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "routing mongoserver" is [mongos](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongos/), you can add as many of them as you like. Typical setup is one per app server, collocated with the app server to reduce network latency.

Comment: So you can add a second mongos server and than connect this second server to the same shards and condig servers as the first mongos server?

Comment: Yes, it is the recommended setup: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-components/#production-configuration

Comment: Tx. I will try to do this.